# This way of using struct puzzled me

Tags: c#, struct, interface

As I know before using a struct , I must have a object of it. Then I can't understand the following codes. Maybe the problem is somewhere else I can't find. Please help me.

```
namespace Ixxat.Vci3.Bal.Can
{

    public struct CanBitrate
    {
        .....
        public static CanBitrate Cia10KBit { get; }

        public static CanBitrate Cia125KBit { get; }

        public static CanBitrate Cia20KBit { get; }

        public static CanBitrate Cia250KBit { get; }

        public static CanBitrate Cia500KBit { get; }

        public static CanBitrate Cia50KBit { get; }

        public static CanBitrate Cia800KBit { get; }

        //     Gets an array of all available CiA baud rates.
        public static CanBitrate[] CiaBitRates { get; }

        //     Gets a empty bit timing value.
        public static CanBitrate Empty { get; }

        public string Name { get; }


        public override sealed string ToString();
    }
}
```

Abrove all is the given interface, I think the "Cia125KBit" is a function of the struct. Then in another file, there is a function like this:

```
 mCanCtl.InitLine( CanOperatingModes.Standard | CanOperatingModes.ErrFrame
                        , CanBitrate.Cia125KBit);
```

the definition of the InitLine is as follows:

```
public interface ICanControl : ICanSocket
{
   ...
   void InitLine(CanOperatingModes operatingMode, CanBitrate bitrate);
}
```

My question is , CanBitrate is the name of struct, why it can be used in the function like CanBitrate.Cia125KBit?  As I learned, It should like this

CanBitrate a;

a.Can125KBit;

I think there must something I am unknown or misunderstand . Ask for help.

Comment: thats cause everything is defined static. Static means its available for every instance of the given type. So u need to access it through the classname instead of an instance

Comment: I beleive the correct description of static is that it belongs to the type itself rather than to an instance of the type

Comment: You can't declare a property with only `{ get; }` in a struct, do you have a body for it? It is easier to help if you post code that compiles, that way we can answer the right question, not wondering about what you really meant.

Comment: This struct is not mine. It is an interface of a usb-device , The question is not there @AlbinSunnanbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cia125KBit` is a static member which means that it can be accessed without creating an instance of the struct. As MSDN puts it,

> Use the static modifier to declare a static member, which belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object.

To contrast this, the member `Name` is not declared as static. Therefore, trying to do something like `CanBitRate.Name` would throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're missing is the keyword `static`. A method, property or field of a class can be declared `static` to decouple it from individual instances, meaning that it's accessed through the class itself as opposed to objects.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Cia125KBit` is a static member. Static members are not bound to any instance and can be accessed only via class/struct name.